# how to continue same countdown timer in next form?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a test paper where counter is there. I have to continue it as user clicked on next button..

Code i used for timer on form 3 is:

```
Public Class Form3
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Private alarmTime As Date

    Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.alarmTime = Date.Now.AddMinutes(60)
    Me.Timer1.Start()


End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If alarmTime < Date.Now Then
        Me.Timer1.Stop()
        MessageBox.Show("Time's up.")
    Else
        Dim remainingTime As TimeSpan = Me.alarmTime.Subtract(Date.Now)

        Me.Label6.Text = String.Format("{0}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}", _
                                       remainingTime.Hours, _
                                       remainingTime.Minutes, _
                                       remainingTime.Seconds)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim frmDialogue As New Form8

    frmDialogue.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put all the code for your timer into a `Module`. That way you can access it anywhere in your application. I would also add two new events `Elapsed` and `TimerComplete` so multiple *objects* and *forms* can subscribe to the key actions you wish to perform with when the timer ticks.

Here's the `AppTimer` module that's accessible from anywhere:

```vb
Module AppTimer
    Private alarmTime As Date
    Private WithEvents timer As Timer = New Timer()

    Public Sub Start(ByVal time as Date)
        alarmTime = time
        timer.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub TimerTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e as EventArgs)
        Handles timer.Tick

        If alarmTime < Date.Now Then
            timer.Stop()
            RaiseEvent TimerComplete("Time's up.")
        Else
            Dim remainingTime As Timespan = alarmTime.Subtract(Date.Now)
            RaiseEvent Elapsed(remainingTime)
        End If
    End Sub

    'This will fire when the duration of the timer has elapsed
    Public Event TimerComplete As Action(Of String)

    'This will fire each time the timer ticks unless it's finished
    Public Event Elapsed As Action(Of Timespan)
End Module
```

Now in `Form3_Load(...)` you can set up the timer like so:

```
    AppTimer.Start(Date.Now.AddMinutes(60))
```

And then in any form you wish to do something when these events fire, create two new methods and hook them up with `AddHandler`:

```
AddHandler AppTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf HandleElapsed
AddHandler AppTimer.TimerComplete, AddressOf HandleComplete

Private Sub HandleElapsed(ByVal remainingTime As Timespan)
    Me.Label6.Text = String.Format("{0}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}", _
                                   remainingTime.Hours, _
                                   remainingTime.Minutes, _
                                   remainingTime.Seconds)
End Sub

Private Sub HandleComplete(ByVal message As String)
    MessageBox.Show(message)
End Sub
```

---

It's also worth noting that you can hook up events with `lambdas`:

```
AddHandler AppTimer.Elapsed, Sub(remainingTime)
                                 String.Format("{0}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}", _
                                     remainingTime.Hours, _
                                     remainingTime.Minutes, _
                                     remainingTime.Seconds) 
                             End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @teena gupta - Did this help you achieve what you wanted to?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a main mdi window which will hold the timer and there will be sub windows in the which can access the parent timer or even the mdi itself can close all the test paper form and show msg box for time up when the time is up.